# Cannot read property Undefined property error in console - React Component render method

Tags: reactjs, redux

Seeing 
bundle.js:94016 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '**propertyValue**' of undefined
    at Component.render (bundle.js:94016)
error in console - this value is the response from API call in my action creator - but if it is printing the value in action creator response as well as the logic also works in the render method of the component. What am I missing here..?

Component:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    //action creator call from component
    this.props.getData(apiURL);
  }
render() {
const propValue = this.props.apiResponseData.propertyValue;
return (
  <div>
    <div>
      {(propValue === 'red') ? <RED /> : <BLUE />}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Need an advance description and code of the segment. I think that you have correct state, but you have not correctly carried into your component.

code[10] conosle.log(this.props) Insert this line to check them.

It's working fine. Just check your "this.props" and find your correct path of propertyValue.

If you have no use ImutableJS, it might like that
**"this.props.apiResponseData.count.propertyValue;"**

**Path description as follows**

apiResponseData => propsName

count => reducerName

propertyValue => dataName

[image: enter dd description here]

[image]

Comment: updated my question with code.http://stackoverflow.com/users/7375412/tonyy

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined at Component.render.  Is it component which has a "price" ?

Comment: yea gave the same names - the error is in the render method where I am getting the property value.

Comment: Your "this.props.apiResponseData" is null.

Comment: printing the value in action creator response as well as the logic <= where are you doing printconsole

Comment: You need to check your "getData" function which is api caller and return correct response

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the response from an API and hence at the initial time of render it may not be defined and hence yuu get an error

Try this

```
render() {
const propValue = null;
if(this.props.apiResponseData) {
    propValue = this.props.apiResponseData.propertyValue;
}
return (
  <div>
    <div>
      {(propValue === 'red') ? <RED /> : <BLUE />}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```